org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: USE
I have a query that is trying to grab a number of details from a list of defects:
String useIndexPrimary = "USE INDEX (PRIMARY)";     
TypedQuery<Defect> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("select d from "+getEntityName()+" d " + useIndexPrimary + " WHERE d.id in :defectIds", Defect.class);
query.setParameter("defectIds", ids);

Which basically translates to:
SELECT d FROM DefectConcrete d USE INDEX(PRIMARY) WHERE d.id IN defects"

When I try to execute the code I get
2024-07-22 12:01:27,936 [pool-177-thread-2] ::: ERROR com.optimyth.csaas.infrastructure.queues.spring.AnalysisLifeCycleManager - 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process stream for Diff defect.
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: USE near line 1, column 77 [select d from com.optimyth.csaas.metamodel.implementations.DefectConcrete d USE INDEX (PRIMARY) WHERE d.id in :defectIds]

I think I am using "USE INDEX" in the correct place, but I am unsure why am I getting the "unexpected token" issue.

Which rdmbs do you use?

The 'USE INDEX' which you have used in the query is causing the issue. JPQL is a database agnostic language while the 'USE INDEX' clause is database specific. Kindly try removing the clause.
The correct query should be
SELECT d FROM DefectConcrete d WHERE d.id IN :defectIds


That is not the case. I use it in other queries without any issues.
